# VS2008 takes ages to close

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Using for VC++. It runs pretty fast and is generally great, but when exiting it often locks up (Visual Studio is not responding) for quite a long time. It seems to always exit successfully but what is it doing for all that time? Is it yet another NCB/Intellisense issue?

I have 2 plugins to VS:

- Visual Assist X
- VisualSVN

Comment: Need more information. Perhaps it be from a 3rd party Visual Studio add ons?

Comment: @MitchWheat can you elaborate?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645